# Python reading unicode folder and file names

Tags: python, csv, python-2.7, unicode, filesize

I am new to Python. I am trying to input one path and use `os.walk()` to search all files, and return the files' names.  I also want to use `os.path.getsize()` to get file size, and finally, write them into a csv file.

However, if the file name is not in English, but in Chinese, German, French, etc, Python cannot recognize it and does not return the size of the file.  I'd like to use `os.path.getsize(path)` (referring to the example below), but it does not recognize the file's name. How can I let Python recognize the file's name and return the size of these kind of files?

For example: the file's name is: `"Показатели естественного и миграционного прироста до 2030г.doc"`. `path="C:\xxxx\xxx\xxxx\Показатели естественного и миграционного прироста до 2030г.doc"`

Answer (score 3):

If you pass a Unicode input to `os.walk()` you will get back file-names as Unicode as well.

The following should work for you

```
your_base_path = u"C:\\Directory" # note this is Unicode
for root, dirs, files in os.walk(your_base_path):
    for f in files:
         print os.stat(os.path.join(root, f)).st_size
```

Comment: [undecodable filenames may be returned as bytes on Python 2 on POSIX](http://stackoverflow.com/q/21772271/4279) (`os.stat()` itself should work fine with bytes there. You might need `os.chdir()` (twice) to avoid `os.path.join(unicode, bytes)`).