# Python os.walk encode character error

Tags: python, python-2.7, character-encoding, python-2.x

I've got a function:

```
for root, dirs, files in os.walk(directory):
    for file in files:
        if fnmatch.fnmatch(file, '*.php*'):
            path = os.path.join(root, file)
            new = change_file_name(file)
            replace_dict[file] = new
            os.rename(root + os.sep + file, root + os.sep + new)
```

But when In some file is polish character (in this example "ż") I'm getting an error:

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/root/environments/whois/local/lib/python2.7/site-packages/flask/app.py", line 1982, in wsgi_app
    response = self.full_dispatch_request()
  File "/root/environments/whois/local/lib/python2.7/site-packages/flask/app.py", line 1614, in full_dispatch_request
    rv = self.handle_user_exception(e)
  File "/root/environments/whois/local/lib/python2.7/site-packages/flask/app.py", line 1517, in handle_user_exception
    reraise(exc_type, exc_value, tb)
  File "/root/environments/whois/local/lib/python2.7/site-packages/flask/app.py", line 1612, in full_dispatch_request
    rv = self.dispatch_request()
  File "/root/environments/whois/local/lib/python2.7/site-packages/flask/app.py", line 1598, in dispatch_request
    return self.view_functions[rule.endpoint](**req.view_args)
  File "./test.py", line 136, in wayback
    out = download_wayback(domain,data_od,data_do,timestamp)
  File "./wayback.py", line 121, in download_wayback
    for root, dirs, files in os.walk(unicode(directory)):
  File "/root/environments/whois/lib/python2.7/os.py", line 294, in walk
    for x in walk(new_path, topdown, onerror, followlinks):
  File "/root/environments/whois/lib/python2.7/os.py", line 294, in walk
    for x in walk(new_path, topdown, onerror, followlinks):
  File "/root/environments/whois/lib/python2.7/os.py", line 294, in walk
    for x in walk(new_path, topdown, onerror, followlinks):
  File "/root/environments/whois/lib/python2.7/os.py", line 294, in walk
    for x in walk(new_path, topdown, onerror, followlinks):
  File "/root/environments/whois/lib/python2.7/os.py", line 284, in walk
    if isdir(join(top, name)):
  File "/root/environments/whois/lib/python2.7/genericpath.py", line 41, in isdir
    st = os.stat(s)
UnicodeEncodeError: 'ascii' codec can't encode character u'\u017c' in position 85: ordinal not in range(128)
```

Is there a way to fix it? I dont wanna change file names.

Comment: Python 3 might work better for this task.

Comment: see https://stackoverflow.com/questions/21772271/unicodedecodeerror-when-performing-os-walk