# Handling backslash escapes in filenames read from a file

Tags: python, filenames, text-processing

**TL;DR**: text file contains strings that represent backslash escapes; how do I use them as input to `os.stat()` ?

I've an input file `input.txt`:

```
./with\backspace
./with\nnewline
```

Processing them with simple loop doesn't work:

```
>>> import os
>>> with open('input.txt') as f:
...     for line in f:
...         os.stat(line.strip())
... 
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "<stdin>", line 3, in <module>
FileNotFoundError: [Errno 2] No such file or directory: './with\\backspace'
```

Using `.decode("unicode_escape")` as suggested in [another question](https://stackoverflow.com/a/1885197/3701431) works only partially - the first line in the file fails, the second with `\n` doesn't.

---

Sidenote: The input filenames have `./` and I know I can just use `os.listdir('.')` and iterate over files till I find the right ones. That's not my objective. The objective is processing filenames that contain backslash escapes from a file.

---

Additional test:

```
>>> import os
>>> with open('./input.txt') as f:
...     for l in f:
...         os.stat(l.strip().decode('unicode_escape'))
... 
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "<stdin>", line 3, in <module>
AttributeError: 'str' object has no attribute 'decode'
>>> with open('./input.txt') as f:
...     for l in f:
...         try:
...             os.stat(l.strip().encode('utf-8').decode('unicode_escape'))
...             print(l.strip())
...         except:
...             pass
... 
os.stat_result(st_mode=33188, st_ino=1053469, st_dev=2049, st_nlink=1, st_uid=1000, st_gid=1000, st_size=0, st_atime=1536468565, st_mtime=1536468565, st_ctime=1536468565)
./with\nnewline
```

---

Writing explicit string with [`os.fsencode()`](https://stackoverflow.com/a/22314324/3701431) works:

```
>>> os.stat(os.fsencode('with\x08ackspace'))
os.stat_result(st_mode=33188, st_ino=1053465, st_dev=2049, st_nlink=1, st_uid=1000, st_gid=1000, st_size=0, st_atime=1536468565, st_mtime=1536468565, st_ctime=1536468565)
```

However, with multiple variations on the same command, I still can't read the string from the file such that `os.stat()` accepts it.

```
>>> with open('./input.txt') as f:
...      for l in f:
...          os.stat(os.fsdecode( bytes(l.strip(),'utf-8').decode('unicode_escape').encode('latin1') ) )
... 
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "<stdin>", line 3, in <module>
FileNotFoundError: [Errno 2] No such file or directory: './with\x08ackslash'
```

Comment: Please clarify what the correct resulting transformation should be for the two samples.

Comment: @wallyk  I'm not sure what you mean by " correction resulting transformation" phrase, so please clarify. The objective is to pass each string as valid  pathname to `os.stat()`. As you can see from two examples, passing string as read from file and with `.decode()` produce a string that cannot be interpreted by `os.stat()`.  Files with such filenames exist on my filesystem and I need a Pythonic way of accessing them. Does that help ?

Comment: So is the `\b` a backspace or is it a directory separator follow by a `b`?

Comment: @StephenRauch I'm working on Linux, so it's not directory separator. The file is created with `touch$'\b'ackspace'`. So `\b` in the filename is the actual backslash byte. In the `input.txt` that's a string.  As I mentioned in the question, I've looked at a related question that suggests using `.decode('unicode_escape')` on a string, however that doesn't work.  I'll edit an answer to add more output in a second

Comment: I would like to say that putting a backspace into your filename is an extraordinarily bad idea.

Comment: Have you tried: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1885181/how-do-i-un-escape-a-backslash-escaped-string-in-python ?

Comment: @StephenRauch  I'm very well aware of that. Not the first day of dealing  with filenames on Linux. However, I am trying to anticipate such filenames from another user if they use my scripts. It's the same reasoning as to why in bash  we do `while IFS= read -r line; do ..; done < input.txt` We can't assume `input.txt` won't have backslashes in text, or leading whitespace in the line.

Comment: @StephenRauch Yes I have tried the linked suggestion. I actually linked it in my question.  The added output at the end of the question also shows the linked suggestion doesn't help.

Comment: At work I have Linux readily available, at home Windows.  Wish I could be more helpful.. Good luck.

Comment: @StephenRauch No worries. Thanks for attempting to help anyway.

Answer (score 1):

Works in macos:

```
touch $'with\backspace'
touch $'with\newline'
echo $'./with\\backspace\n./with\\newline' > input.txt
python
>>> import os
>>> with open('./input.txt') as f:
...     for l in f:
...         os.stat(l.strip().decode('unicode_escape'))
posix.stat_result(st_mode=33188, st_ino=8604304962, st_dev=16777220, st_nlink=1, st_uid=501, st_gid=20, st_size=0, st_atime=1536469815, st_mtime=1536469815, st_ctime=1536469815)
posix.stat_result(st_mode=33188, st_ino=8604305024, st_dev=16777220, st_nlink=1, st_uid=501, st_gid=20, st_size=0, st_atime=1536470112, st_mtime=1536470112, st_ctime=1536470112)
```

That's with Python 2.7.14 on Darwin Kernel Version 17.7.0.

Comment: Tested the same with Python 2.7.15. `OSError: [Errno 2] No such file or directory: './with\x08ackslash'`

Comment: Nevermind. I've realized the input file was incorrect.  Does work indeed.

Answer (score 0):

I've realized after about 2 hours of going over this that the input file contained `./with\backslash` while the actual filename is created via `touch with$'\b'ackspace`. Thus [Health Raftery's answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/52241562/3701431) works, but only for Python 2. In  Python 3 you get  `AttributeError: 'str' object has no attribute 'decode'` since string [in Python 3 are already a unicode strings](https://stackoverflow.com/a/28584017/3701431).

In the process, I may have found a better approach via [os.fsencode()](https://docs.python.org/3.4/library/os.html#os.fsencode) 
referenced in [jfs's answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/22314324/3701431).

```
import os

with open('./input.txt') as f:
    for l in f:
        # alternatively one can use 
        # bytes(l.strip(),sys.getdefaultencoding())
        bytes_filename =  bytes(l.strip(), 'utf-8').decode('unicode_escape')
        f_stat = os.stat(os.fsdecode( bytes_filename ) )
        print(l.strip(),f_stat)
```

Since I use mostly Python 3, this is what I was looking for. However,  [Health Raftery's answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/52241562/3701431) is nontheless valid, hence +1'ed.